# Java error log output Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have a php application that calls java application via `exec` like this:

```
$result = exec("java -jar " . $path . " " . $input, $output, $return);
```

On standard LAMP/WAMP stack if java app throws an exception it is written to Apache log. I've changed my development stack and I no longer get the exception logged.

My current stack is this:

```
Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) 64bit
Nginx 1.4.3
PHP-FPM 5.5.3
```

Neither nginx nor php logs contain the exception thrown by Java app. How do I capture it?

**UPDATE:** Just to note - if there is a php syntax error for instance, it gets logged to `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: Does PHP’s exceptions get logged? (exceptions == errors, notices and that stuff)

Comment: @Smar I've got this in my `/etc/php5/php-fpm.conf` : `error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log`, but that log file is dormant

Comment: I’ve never really gotten php’s own logging methods to work sanely. Something like track_errors in php.ini (or through fpm ini setting thingy) may help. Anyway, I’d guess you don’t have proper logging for your virtual server in Nginx, the errors, as long as they’re logged in first place, goes to there. And AFAIK the Java errors should go to same log file.