# vertx.io vertical stop working on exception

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx3

Working with vertx.io 3.0.0, when an exception is thrown and not catch in the JAVA API the vertical freezes. We are working on a single server environment, the server is not in a cluster.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch the current thread's unhanded exception using:

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
     new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
     LOGGER.error(t + " throws exception: " + e);
  }
});
```

If you are using multiple vertical, I would recommend that you add `UncaughtExceptionhandler` for each vertical, as each vertical will have its own event loop and hence, its own thread.

There is a similar question for java already answered: [Java uncaught global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422366/java-uncaught-global-exception-handler)