# closing muliple process with different affinity android

Tags: java, android, affinity

I am  doing a global exception handling for my application with [defaultuncaughtexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422366/java-uncaught-global-exception-handler) thread, for which I have created another process with different affinity. After the exception is handled I restart my package with launcher intent but all the previous instances of my application which is running in the background and hindering with my shared preference. I want to close all the instance of the application. I tried **killing pid, killing background process with package name, finish, finish affinity** but nothing helped.

Any help would be appreciated