# Creating a custom crash reporter

Tags: android, error-handling

I'm looking to report my app crashes to a custom backend (instead of using an existing crash reporter such as Firebase).

How can I catch fatal crashes in Android?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Fabric. They even have a crash listener so that when that listener is called you can put the log/exception to your custom server. Also, it will be available in the Fabric console. I would suggest you to use Fabric as it has many cool features.

Comment: Use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and point it to the backend of your choice.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 Fabric is now part of Firebase, which we don't want to use at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to write an Exception Handler like this.

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {

        // Do your code here
        Log.i("Localized_Message", exception.getLocalizedMessage());

    }
}
```

Then use it by calling this class from your activity.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler((Activity) MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); // Change Main Activity with your Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to write a class that implements interface  java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.
In your implementation method public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex), the exception object is "ex" and you could do what you want there.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this? What would I do with this class?

Comment: Read the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943288/how-to-implement-uncaughtexception-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422366/java-uncaught-global-exception-handler